# How can I define a type that can be both a single type or an array of type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following definitions for props that I use in my react component. Basically allowing the passing in of either a single validator or multiple. I've tried various combinations of defiing the type and I just can't seem to get this working

```
export type Validator = {
   message: string,
   test: (text: string) => boolean
}

export type ValidatedInputProps = InputProps & {
   validator: Validator | Validator[], // how am i supposed to type this?
   skipBlurIfInvalid?: boolean,
}

//usage:
if (isArray(validator)) {
   for (let v of validator) { //TS2488: Type 'Validator | Validator[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
      const {message, test} = v
      if (!test(value)) {
         this.showError(message)
         return false
      }
   }
} else {
   const {message, test} = validator //TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Validator | Validator[]'.
   if (!test(value)) {
      this.showError(message)
      return false
   }
}
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: Where are you getting this `isArray` from? Shouldn't it be `Array.isArray`? It is weird that this code is not working as it fits perfectly in the third example of TS's Union Types documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types